# Как проверить, работает ли цикл Или выполнить код когда он закончится?

Tags: javascript

У меня появилась надобность проверить цикл на работу, не был ли он остановлен (не только break) (или выполнить код по его завершению, это тоже решит проблему). Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Вы чудесно задали Ваш вопрос и всех заинтересовали. Теперь, пожалуйста, объясните человеческим языком и с кодом, чего Вам надо.

Comment: Мне нужно проверить, не был ли цикл for или while остановлен

Comment: Что это, черт возьми, значит?

Comment: Я не знаю как проще объяснить чего я хотел

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Чтобы проверить не был ли цикл остановлен проверьте в нужном месте условие завершения цикла, если оно `true`, то, скорее всего, цикл отработал и не был досрочно завершен.

Comment: `while (true) { break; }` - проверьте.

Comment: Такой цикл не может сам завершиться, следовательно его остановили.